# Power Shell File Upload to SFTP with File Existence Check

Tags: powershell, file-upload, sftp

I have a requirement to upload multiple files to SFTP server from my machine using powershell.i have created the following scripts for the same . the script is working fine . but need to check file existence before upload to SFTP server .

the following are the script i used for upload

```
$username = "UserName"

$password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$server = "xxxxx"

$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList  
  $username,$password

Get-SFTPSession | Remove-SFTPSession

$SFTPSession=New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -Port xxxx

$FilePath = get-childitem "D:\Test\xx*"

$SftpPath = '/D:/xxx/xxx/Test'

 ForEach ($LocalFile in $FilePath)
{
Set-SFTPFile -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionID -LocalFile $LocalFile.fullname -RemotePath $SftpPath -Overwrite
}
```

Please any body advice me on to check  multiple files existence before uploading and only upload files which is not exist in server .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to share what SFTP library are you using. There are no SFTP cmdlets in PowerShell on its own. Is it Posh-SSH?

Comment: yes , i have used Posh-SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Posh-SSH, you want to use the [`Test-SFTPPath` cmdlet](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Test-SFTPPath.md):

```
if (Test-SFTPPath -SFTPSession $session -Path $Path)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: : Thank you for your reply . i am not that much familiar with powershell ,  i have doubt , can we only possibile to  check file exist with specific session ? i need  to check same file is exist in a specific folder do we possible to do this or will give session madatory ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you ask for.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i will try with above answer ,

Comment: Thank u : i tried with above and worked successfully.