# Upload file using SFTP in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, azure-powershell

I am trying the below command but didn't get any output:

```
echo "put C:\Users\abhishek.chawla\Desktop\AbhishekC_bills.zip deployment/AbhishekC_bills.zip" | sftp TESTSHELTER@shelter-ftp.outlinesys.com
```

Do I need to add the password too? If yes, then where to add the password?

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround you can follow ,

*To provide the password into the command for upload files to SFTP using PowerShell through Winscp below is the example of code*.

`cmdltes`:-

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx...="
}
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
try
{
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    $session.PutFiles("C:\users\export.txt","/Outbox/").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

*For complete information please refer this* **BLOG**|[***Use WinSCP to Upload Files to SFTP Site With PowerShell***](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/powershell-sftp/#use-winscp-to-upload-files-to-sftp-site-with-powershell) .

*For more information regarding similar issue please refer the below links*:-

- **SO THREAD**| [***Power Shell File Upload to SFTP with File Existence Check***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574274/power-shell-file-upload-to-sftp-with-file-existence-check) & [***Upload file to SFTP using PowerShell***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732025/upload-file-to-sftp-using-powershell) .